# Angular UI Pagination with REST/JSON Values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

Has anyone undertaken pagination in AngularJS using Angular UI Pagination for JSON results. I see how to setup the paging visualization, but am curious on how others have implemented displaying the results per page since I am using ng-repeat to output my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have located a wonderful custom directive for paging, including async server side paging here:

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Props to @michael bromley